# MQ V7.5.3 can anyone please advise on taking dump of subscriptions which are created by MQ API

Tags: ibm-mq

Thanks for going thru this question. 
We have installed ITCAM agent on MQ V7.5.0.3. Currently we had a scenario to clean out all the MQ objects and recreate it. While configuring ITCAM agent on MQ, there were few auto-created Subscriptions on Qmgr.

While taking dmpmqcfg -m  these subscriptions are not captured ( as per info center "The dmpmqcfg utility dumps only subscriptions of type MQSUBTYPE_ADMIN, that is, only subscriptions that are created using the MQSC command DEFINE SUB or its PCF equivalent. Subscriptions that are created by applications using the MQSUB MQI call of type MQSUBTYPE_API are not part of the queue manager configuration, even if durable, and so are not dumped by dmpmqcfg")

Can anyone please advise how to take dump of all the subscriptions irrespective of created by DEFINE SUB or by some API's.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can issue the command `DISPLAY SUB(*) TYPE(API) ALL` to see them all.

`dmpmqcfg` does not dump them out because replaying them as `DEFINE SUB` commands would create `TYPE(ADMIN)` subscriptions.

Comment: You're welcome, remember to click on the tick to accept the answer if you like it.